# is there a way of hooking into a currently running python script to see whats going on?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python script that occasionally freezes and I'd like to find out why? Is there a way to hook into a python script and see what the variables are what line its on and/or what its doing?

Comment: You mean the script is already running, and you somehow want to attach a Python debugger to the running script, without modifying the script in any way?

Comment: Yes, its already running and I want to see whats going on without modifying the script.

Comment: If the script is already running, I think you are out of luck.  All options I'm aware of either require a line of code to be injected into our script or to start the script using some debugging server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I attach a remote debugger to a Python process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543196/how-do-i-attach-a-remote-debugger-to-a-python-process)

Answer (score 1):

#### Original Answer

Use a debugger as shown in the answers to [How do I attach a remote debugger to a Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/544838/156755)

Once attached, you can pause execution and examine variables, the current stack, etc...

#### Update

As pointed out in the comments, the linked debuggers apparently require the process to be launched in a particular manner. Visual Studio (With [Python Tools](https://pytools.codeplex.com/) installed) [does support](http://Visual%20Studio%20includes%20support%20for%20debugging%20applications%20including%20attaching%20to%20running%20processes,%20evaluating%20expressions%20in%20the%20watch%20and%20immediate%20windows,%20and%20inspecting%20local%20variables,%20step%20in,%20out,%20and%20over%20statements,%20set%20the%20next%20statement,%20and%20breaking%20on%20exceptions.%20With%20Python%20Tools%20for%20Visual%20Studio%20installed,%20all%20of%20this%20functionality%20is%20available%20for%20Python%20projects.) attaching to a running process.

Comment: None of the answers to that question support attaching to a script that wasn't already instrumented for debugging

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Thanks, I hadn't spotted that. I know it's something Visual Studio is capable of doing, I simply assumed others would be equally capable. Example of how to do it in VS: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Debugging (Assuming you have Python Tools for VS installed) `Visual Studio includes support for debugging applications including attaching to running processes, evaluating expressions in the watch and immediate windows, and inspecting local variables, step in, out, and over statements, set the next statement, and breaking on exceptions.`

Answer (score 0):

For the case where the binary was not prepared in advance:

- [pydbattach](https://github.com/albertz/pydbattach), hacked together by me, not updated since a long time
- [Google pyringe](https://github.com/google/pyringe), last update 2014
- [pyrasite](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite), last update 2017
- [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy/), sampling only, dump stack traces
- [Pyflame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame), sampling only
- [PyStack](https://bloomberg.github.io/pystack/), dump stack traces including locals

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are several ways to debug a Python script to identify the cause of occasional freezes. Here are some common techniques:

1. Print Statements:
   Insert print statements at various points in your code to print the values of variables and control flow. This is a simple and quick way to get an idea of what your script is doing.
   print("Reached point A")
   print(variable_name)
2. Logging:
   Utilize the `logging` module to log messages at different levels (info, debug, error, etc.) throughout your script. This can provide more detailed information than print statements.

   import logging
   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
   logging.debug("This is a debug message")
3. Interactive Debugger (PDB):
   You can use Python's built-in debugger, PDB (Python Debugger), to step through your code and inspect variables interactively. Insert the following line at the point where you want to start debugging:

   import pdb;
   pdb.set_trace()

   Run your script, and it will stop at this line, allowing you to inspect variables, step through code, and identify issues.
4. Tracing:
   The `trace` module allows you to trace the execution of your code, showing which lines are executed and in what order.

   import trace
   tracer = trace.Trace(ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix], trace=1)
   tracer.run('your_script.py')
   This generates a report that you can inspect to see the sequence of function calls and lines executed.

You can then replace `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` with `import pdbpp; pdbpp.set_trace()` or `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` for more features.

Choose the method that best fits your needs or combine multiple techniques for more thorough debugging.

Comment: Your answer provides a good amount of information but could benefit with examples!