# Debugging python with mod_fastcgi

Tags: python, apache, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I running apache with mod_fastcgi to run python scripts (using Ubuntu OS).

How can I debug python with fastcgi? I put a `pdb.set_trace()` call in my script, but when loading the page in a browser nothing happens in the console from which I ran the apache start command (`/etc/init.d/apache2 start`).
Where should the python debugger run??

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach pdb to a running instance of your FCGI script, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543196/how-do-i-attach-a-remote-debugger-to-a-python-process) for a How To.

This information is also stated in the [FCGI FAQ](http://www.fastcgi.com/om_archive/words/FAQ.htm).