# Python: Create another python console window sharing same data

Tags: python, console, window

I'm trying to make a debug console window appear (Needs to share data with the script), still having the main console open. The only way I know how to do it is to execute a second script, and share data with a file..

I would like for the second window to be an actual console.

I'm on Windows 7, and my script doesn't need to be very compatible.

Comment: you mean: compatible = cross-platform?

Comment: Doesn't need to be compatible - Should run on my PC, but I don't care about other platforms, So compatible = cross-platform

Comment: You probably want to connect to the process via some remote debugging tool. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543196/how-do-i-attach-a-remote-debugger-to-a-python-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows you can use win32console module to open a second console for your child thread(since you want them to share same data) output. This is the most simple and easiest way that works if you are on windows.

Here is a sample code:

```
import win32console
import threading
from time import sleep

def child_thread():
    win32console.FreeConsole() #Frees child_thread from using main console
    win32console.AllocConsole() #Creates new console and all input and output of the child_thread goes to this new console
   
    while True:
        print("This is in child_thread console and the count is:",count)
        #prints in new console dedicated to this thread

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    count = 0
    threading.Thread(target=child_thread, args=[]).start()
    while True:
        count+=1
        print("Hello from the main console - this is count:", count)
        #prints in main console
        sleep(1)
        #and whatever else you want to do in ur main process
```

There is also a better method of using queues from the [queue module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) as it gives you a more control over race conditions.

Here is the [win32console module documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32console.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider going GUI on your application and popping to windows which will have input and output(textboxes) designed as console. Technically both windows will run as one application thus having access to the same namespaces. For wrapping python in GUI check out python [Wx](http://www.wxpython.org/) and [Python TkInte](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)r. Best of luck.

PS And it will be pretty compatible :)

Comment: Thanks, gonna check that out :)