# How can I get a REPL on a production-deployed Pyramid install?

Tags: passenger, pyramid, read-eval-print-loop

One of the clear advantages of LISP environments (Clojure etc) is the ability to hook up and get a Read-eval-print-loop (REPL) on a running instance - thus being able to call production code and generally interact with the production system at runtime - via the REPL.

I am currently working with a Python/Pyramid stack that is deployed on top of Nginx/Phusion passenger - and I find myself many times being forced to "perform live surgery" on the DB, when in fact I would much prefer to call a function that exists inside the deployed Python code...

Is there a possibility to get a production-attached REPL for my setup?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to REPL in the same process, but you are probably looking for pshell.

```
pshell production.ini
```

Comment: Thanks, Antoine. I gather that this is used at launch time (instead of e.g. pserve) during debug sessions - but can not be used to attach to a production instance. Correct?

Comment: Correct, you cannot attach to a process using it. At least, if you can, I don't know how. But you can run it while the production application is running, as a separate process. It may be useful if you want to query the database for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyCharm to [attach](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/attaching-to-process.html) to running Python process:

> PyCharm makes it possible to attach to a Python process, while running
>   a Python script launched either outside of PyCharm, or inside PyCharm

Also, take a look at these questions:
[How do I attach a remote debugger to a Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/543196/95735)
[python: is it possible to attach a console into a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4163964/95735)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fancy try [pyramid_notebook](https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/pyramid_notebook). It gives you IPython Notebook shell for your Pyramid website - Notebook being pretty much the culmination of 40 years of shell user interface development. It's more complex to set up, but once done, you get a interactive, secure, shell session your web browser with a single click.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the project.